# socket library for MS-DOS (C language)

Tags: c, api, sockets, dos

I need to write client and server applications for MS-DOS using C language.
I don't want to start from scratch and implement sockets.
Can you advice me library in which socket functionality is implemented and for which exist good manuals and examples.

I already tried mTCP library: I got source files from it, added sources from example file and tried to Compile in Turbo C, but it raises a lot of errors it will be very hard task for me to cope with them.

Comment: OT: Why do you need to build new things on stone age old DOS?

Comment: As far as I know DOS is installed on some embedded systems. True this or false, on some equipment that my employee produces (ex. for ship navigation) embedded systems with DOS OS are used.

Comment: "(ex. for ship navigation)" This makes me very worried...from now on, I'll only board on ships that navigate using the tried and true compass-and-maps navigation system :)

Comment: @Manjabes Do you know that some IBM 1800 machines (from 1965+) was yet at work in 2006 on some nuclear power station in Canada (see [Russian Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Проблема_2038_года), don't know English link)? There is a programmers saying in Russia: _Работает - не трогай_ (in English: _Does it works? Don't touch it!_)

Comment: While it is certainly true that there is no need to replace legacy systems simply because they are old, this request seems to imply that a legacy system is being touched. Perhaps now would be a good time to consider replacing it or some part of it. If only by porting to something maintained like FreeDOS, which I believe has a fairly standard socket interface.

Comment: Watt-32 http://home.broadpark.no/~gvanem/ It does not support Turbo C but many others.

Comment: @Yury Yes, and I also know about "не мешай механизму работать" regarding Иж and М motorbikes, but a legacy system doing its job somewhere is one thing, but a new development (or addition) in 2012 on MS-DOS is a different beast altogether! And not one I personally would feel that comfortable with :)

Answer (score 0):

Try libnet. According to it's web page (http://libnet.sourceforge.net/) it supports DOS systems (djgpp compiler), though I personally haven't tried it on DOS.

Comment: Ooh yeah, how long haven't I read this name `djgpp` ... ;-)

Comment: @zlabs.eu according to the description on the web page you refered me to, library supports only WinSockets in Dos mode, which means that it can be used from dos prompt under windows, that don`t suits my needs at all. But thanks for info.

Answer (score 0):

There is also WATTCP: http://www.erickengelke.com/wattcp/

Have you tried that?